# Spring taking time to run

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have a spring boot application when i start run its takes time to load
it's stuck at

```
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

After researching I found a solution to make it fast to put this in properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

Now run is faster but insert statements not working i am getting this error

```
ERROR: currval(): currval of sequence "some_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
```

How to resolve this?

either i should solve slowness at startup
or resolve insert issue

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate tries to use global id generator for postgres. to fix this error you  need to disable id-generator mapping through properties file.
eg:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        properties:
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        hibernate:
          use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
```

Comment: I tried this but no use